# Hiding trivial conditions when using Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I use Reduce to find conditions on some parameters such that certain inequalities are fulfilled. An additional condition is that all parameters are positive. The first problem is that I have to mention all those conditions when calling Reduce, and the second is that they appear in the result and make it less readable.

I tried to use Assumptions, but it doesn't change the result.

I wonder if it is possible to hide these trivial conditions or at least suppress them in the output?

```
$Assumptions = Flatten[{Thread[{r, p, h, K} > 0], Element[{r, p, h, K}, Reals]}]
Reduce[K*(r - h)/r > 0 && (p*h)/(r - h) < p && K >0 && p>0 && h>0 && r>0,h]
```

Comment: `MemberQ[Keys[Options[Reduce]], Assumptions]` returns `False`, so it is inappropriate to use `$Assumptions` with `Reduce[]`.

Comment: Dmitry, apply `Simplify` to the result of `Reduce`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, this seems to be the most simple and efficient solution so far. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility:

```
conds = K > 0 && p > 0 && h > 0 && r > 0;
Complement[Reduce[K*(r - h)/r > 0 && (p*h)/(r - h) < p && conds, h, Reals], conds]
   0 < h < r/2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not suppress the conditions from the output when inequalities get more complex, e.g., here:
conds = K > 0 && p > 0 && h > 0 && r > 0 && \[Rho] > 0;
Complement[Reduce[K*(r - h)/r > 0 && (p*h)/(r - \[Rho] - h) < p && conds, h, Reals], conds]

Comment: Then you can use `Simplify[]`, which does take assumptions: `With[{conds = K > 0 && p > 0 && h > 0 && r > 0 && ρ > 0}, Assuming[conds, Simplify[Reduce[K*(r - h)/r > 0 && (p*h)/(r - ρ - h) < p && conds, h, Reals]]]]`.